# How to set the right type for PayloadAction?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to set the type for `PayloadAction<LoginError>` as the payload for when I get an error from logging in is:

```
{
    message: string,
    status: number,
}
```

In my code, I defined a type for that payload as `LoginError`, and added it as the type for `login.rejected`

```
type LoginResponse = {
    data: UserLogin
}

type LoginError = {
    status: number;
    message: string;
}

export interface AuthInterface {
    loading: boolean;
    userToken: boolean | null;
    error: LoginError | null;
    success: boolean;
}

export interface AuthState {
    auth: AuthInterface;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
    auth: {
        loading: false,
        userToken: null,
        error: null,
        success: false,
    }
}

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (loginData: LoginData, thunkAPI: any) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = loginData;
            //config, data, headers, request, status, statusText
            //{ data: resData, headers: resHeaders } 
            const { data: resData, headers: resHeaders } = await serveraxios.post<LoginResponse>(
                "/login",
                {
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                },
                {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            );
            console.log(resData);
            console.log(resHeaders);
            return resData;
        }
        catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message));
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({
                status: error.response.data.status,
                message: error.response.data.message,
            });
        }
    }
)

export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/logout",
    async() => {
        const res = await serveraxios.post(
            "logout",
            undefined,
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
        console.log(res);
    }
)

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<UserLogin>) => {
            console.log(action.payload);
            state.auth.loading = false;
            state.auth.success = true;
        })
        .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<LoginError>) => {
            console.log(action.payload);
            state.auth.loading = false;
            state.auth.success = false;
            state.auth.error = action.payload;
        })
        
    }
});

export const selectAuth = (state: RootState) => state.auth.auth;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

However, i get the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(actionCreator: AsyncThunkRejectedActionCreator<LoginData, AsyncThunkConfig>, reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<...>>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: WritableDraft<AuthState>, action: { payload: LoginError; type: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: LoginData; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ rejectedWithValue: true; } | ({ ...; } & {})), SerializedError>>'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: LoginData; requestId: string; requestStatus: "rejected"; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; } & ({ rejectedWithValue: true; } | ({ rejectedWithValue: false; } & {})), SerializedError>' is not assignable to type '{ payload: LoginError; type: string; }'.
          Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'LoginError'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, { payload: LoginError; type: string; }>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<AuthState>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkRejectedActionCreator<LoginData, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2769)
```

However when I assign the type to PayloadAction as any as in: `PayloadAction<any>` I dont get any error.

Could someone explain to me how to set the correct type for my PayloadAction?